# How can i call another component template div Id to another component

Tags: angular

Lets say I have two component: "UserPatientsReportFormComponent" and "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent". I want to call "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent" temaplate  id to "UserPatientsReportFormComponent".
I'll share the code below and please let me know the changes I needed to achieve it

This below template code is from "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent" component

```
<div >
    <table id="pdfData" #pdfData *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
      <tr>
        <th>{{hubxReport.categoryName}} + "Test"</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>{{column}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{item.itemTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemValue}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemUnit}}</td>
        <td>{{item.normalRange}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And i want to call the above template here "UserPatientsReportFormComponent"

```
@ViewChild('pdfData') pdfData: ElementRef;
```

and I'm trying to access the template Id in this below function

```
downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {  
    debugger      
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let rows: Array<any> = [];
    let header: Array<any> = [];
    let medicineInfo: any;
    let physicianInfo: any;
    let content=this.pdfData.nativeElement; //--<<here im calling the template id>>--
    let _elementHandlers =  
    {  
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){  
        return true;  
      }  
    };  
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML,15,15,{  
  
            'width':190,  
            'elementHandlers':_elementHandlers  
          });
```

Currently I get an error that says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: Are you trying to access the `pdfData` element located at `UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent` from `UserPatientsReportFormComponent`?

Comment: Yes im trying to access pdfData in UserPatientsReportFormComponent

Comment: Try ViewChildren instead of ViewChild since pdfData is on a ngFor element.

Comment: ok but pdfData is on another component:"UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent " and i'm trying to access it from UserPatientsReportFormComponent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, this is what your components hierarchy looks like:

```html
<app-user-patients-report-form>
  <app-user-patients-report-form-template>
    <table #pdfData>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
  </app-user-patients-report-form-template>
</app-user-patients-report-form>
```

You are trying to call the `pdfData` element (which is a child of `UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent`) as if it's a direct child of `UserPatientsReportFormComponent`. This will not work.

Instead, put this line:

```
@ViewChild('pdfData') public pdfData: ElementRef;
```

inside the actual component that contains `pdfData` which in your case is `UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent` class.

To access that element from `UserPatientsReportFormComponent`, first you need to see your direct child `UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent` via the same `@ViewChild` way as follows:

```
class UserPatientsReportFormComponent {
  @ViewChild(UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent) userPatientReportFormTemplate: UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent;
}
```

Then, inside your `downloadPDF` function, you can try accessing the template as follows:

```
downloadPDF() {
  // ...
  let content = this.userPatientReportFromTemplate?.pdfData?.nativeElement;
  // ...
}
```

#### Careful

You are accessing children via the `@ViewChild` decorator, which are not usually available until the component view is initiated (happens inside `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method). Make sure you are executing the `downloadPDF` method when both components' views are initialised.

Comment: i have an error that says Property 'pdfData' does not exist on type in this line of code "this.userPatientReportFromTemplate?.pdfData?.nativeElement". Actually pdfData is the table Id. Do i need any declaration in UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs I edited the code, make `pdfData` a public variable.

Comment: i got this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pdfData') in this line of code "let content= this.userPatientReportFormTemplate.pdfData.nativeElement;"

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access the nephew of your current component, but you can emit from your component the `nativeElement`.

#### UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent

```js
@Output() pdfDataEmitter: EvenetEmitter<HTMLElement> = new EventEmitter();

@ViewChild('pdfData') set pdfData(element: ElementRef) {
   this.pdfDataEmitter.emit(element.nativeElement);
}
```

#### AppUserPatientsReportForm

```js
   private _pdfDataNativeElement: HTMLElement;
   set pdfDataElement(element: HTMLElement) {
     this._pdfDataNativeElement = element
   }

   get pdfDataElement(): HTMLElement {
     return this._pdfDataNativeElement;
   }
```

```html
 <app-user-patients-report-form-template (pdfDataEmitter)="pdfDataElement = $event">
  </app-user-patients-report-form-template>
```

In this way, you are setting your #pdfElement to his parent without direct access to it.
I prefer this way because you can handle the information instead of having direct access to his property.

Comment: i only need to access pdfData inside this function downloadPDF(). How do i do it

Comment: In this way, inside the `downloadPDF` method, you can access to property like a normal variable (`this.pdfDataElement`)

Comment: i got this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pdfData')

Comment: Where? Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: i get this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML'). In this line of code doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML,15,15,. So i think pdfData is undefine